# getopt finds no ambiguous optional argument

Tags: getopt

I wrote down a shell script which uses the getopt command. The list of long options supplied to the getopt command include the following three different options:

```
localaddress
localport
listen
```

When I run my script with

```
myscript.sh --local xxxx
```

which clearly contains an ambiguous option (--local), getopt returns it as '--local-address' and a zero code.

```
++ getopt -o a:p: --long localaddress:,localport: -- --local 172.30.2.4
+ AUX='-- --localaddress '\''172.30.2.4'\'
```

But if I try

```
myscript.sh --l xxxx
```

here getopt does find it ambiguous:

```
getopt: option `--l' is ambiguous
```

I think this behaviour is weird given that the manual pages of getopt(1) show:

```
Long options may be abbreviated, as long as the abbreviation is not ambiguous.
```

What have I missed?

Thanx in advance

P.D: tested in RHEL5

**Addendum**

After I read the answer of **Jonathan Leffler**, I tried some tests -- pay attention on the colon pattern:

```
# getopt -V
getopt (enhanced) 1.1.4    
# getopt -o a:p: --long localaddress,localport,listen -- --l xxx 
 --localaddress -- 'xxx'
# getopt -o a:p: --long localaddress,localport,listen: -- --l xxx 
getopt: option `--l' is ambiguous
 -- 'xxx'
# getopt -o a:p: --long localaddress,localport:,listen -- --l xxx 
getopt: option `--l' is ambiguous
 -- 'xxx'
# getopt -o a:p: --long localaddress,localport:,listen: -- --l xxx 
getopt: option `--l' is ambiguous
 -- 'xxx'
# getopt -o a:p: --long localaddress:,localport,listen -- --l xxx 
getopt: option `--l' is ambiguous
 -- 'xxx'
# getopt -o a:p: --long localaddress:,localport,listen: -- --l xxx 
getopt: option `--l' is ambiguous
 -- 'xxx'
# getopt -o a:p: --long localaddress:,localport:,listen -- --l xxx 
getopt: option `--l' is ambiguous
 -- 'xxx'
# getopt -o a:p: --long localaddress:,localport:,listen: -- --l xxx 
 --localaddress 'xxx' --
```

**UPDATE on 2014-05-26 -- testing getopt_long(3)**

I created a simple C program to test the getopt_long(3) function.

In my source code, the array of the structure "option" passed to getopt_long(3) contains the definition of the three long options "xxaaa", "xxxyy" and "xxxzz" -- They all start with the same string "xx" to test the ability of getopt_long(3) to detect the ambiguous options.

```
/*
            FIELD NAMES OF option STRUCTURE
      name            has_arg      flag   val
*/
   { "xxaaa",       no_argument,   NULL,   9},
   { "xxxyy",       no_argument,   NULL,   7},
   { "xxxyz",       no_argument,   NULL,   7},
   { "mmmAA",       no_argument,   NULL,   3},
   { "mmmBB", required_argument,   NULL,   3},
```

(see the manual page of  getopt_long(3) for details about the purposes of those fields).

Pay attention on that an ambiguous option as "--xx" has three possible candidates, but "---xxx" has only two ones.

The behaviour of getopt_long changes according to the values of two struct fields named "has_arg" and "val":

```
WHEN
  the value of "val" field is the same in every possible candidate
    AND
  the value of the "has_arg" field is the same in every possible candidate,
THEN
  the function getopt_long wrongly complains NOTHING about ambiguity
  and the first candidate is returned
OTHERWISE
  an error message about ambiguity is reported.
```

From the above example:

```
test 1. "--xxx" is WRONGLY admitted as "--xxxyy".
test 2. "--xx" is properly refused as ambiguous.
test 3. "--mmm" is properly refused as ambiguous.
```

The getopt(1) command assigns a 2 (labeled as LONG_OPT in the source code) in the "val" field of every "user-defined long option". In the case starting this thread, the array of "option" structures would look like:

```
   { "localaddress",    required_argument,   NULL,   2},
   { "localport",       required_argument,   NULL,   2},
```

Therefore the only way to getopt(1) detect an ambiguous long option is that that candidates have different values in their "has_arg" field.

QUESTIONS

```
Q1. Why does getopt_long(3) behave that way?
Q2. Why does getopt_long_only(3) not?
Q3. How can the creators of getopt_long(3) be notified? -- I'm not into the linux kernel
    development nor I do not use to visit linux kernel websites.
```

WORKAROUND SUGGESTION

As I cannot answer Q1 yet, I think the source code of getopt(1) command might be modified to assign different values in the "val" field for each user-defined long option, instead of the same 2 (LONG_OPT) value. As getopt_long(3) can return single ASCII character in the case of short options, those values should fall out of ASCII map --  val >= 256

Comment: When I tested it, I ran: `/usr/gnu/bin/getopt -o a:p: --long localaddress:,localport: -- --local 172.30.2.4 --loc 10.1.2.3` and I got the output (two lines):
``/usr/gnu/bin/getopt: option `--local' is ambiguous`` and
``/usr/gnu/bin/getopt: option `--loc' is ambiguous``.  This is using `getopt (enhanced) 1.1.4` (from `/usr/gnu/bin/getopt --version`) — compiled on Mac OS X (running on 10.9.3, but built on an earlier version).

Answer (score 0):

Very curious! I am at least nominally running the same version of `getopt` (admittedly not on RHEL5, which is fairly old, now, IIRC — not that age has much to do with it), but I can't reproduce the results you get.  For every one of the operational examples in the addendum, I get the warning message `` getopt: option `--l' is ambiguous `` (and the exit status of `getopt` is 1, indicating failure).

#### Test script

```
for la in '' :
do
    for lp in '' :
    do
        for li in '' :
        do
            (
            set -x
            getopt -o a:p: --long localaddress${la},localport${lp},listen${li} -- --l xxx
            )
            echo $?
        done
    done
done
```

#### Example output

```
+ getopt -o a:p: --long localaddress,localport,listen -- --l xxx
getopt: option `--l' is ambiguous
 -- 'xxx'
1
+ getopt -o a:p: --long localaddress,localport,listen: -- --l xxx
getopt: option `--l' is ambiguous
 -- 'xxx'
1
+ getopt -o a:p: --long localaddress,localport:,listen -- --l xxx
getopt: option `--l' is ambiguous
 -- 'xxx'
1
+ getopt -o a:p: --long localaddress,localport:,listen: -- --l xxx
getopt: option `--l' is ambiguous
 -- 'xxx'
1
+ getopt -o a:p: --long localaddress:,localport,listen -- --l xxx
getopt: option `--l' is ambiguous
 -- 'xxx'
1
+ getopt -o a:p: --long localaddress:,localport,listen: -- --l xxx
getopt: option `--l' is ambiguous
 -- 'xxx'
1
+ getopt -o a:p: --long localaddress:,localport:,listen -- --l xxx
getopt: option `--l' is ambiguous
 -- 'xxx'
1
+ getopt -o a:p: --long localaddress:,localport:,listen: -- --l xxx
getopt: option `--l' is ambiguous
 -- 'xxx'
1
```

This is self-consistent and consistent with the documentation.  Can you run the script shown and verify the output?

Comment: The results are: the first test and the last one report 0 (not ambiguous), the other ones report 1 (ambiguous). Tested in RHEL 4 (getopt 1.1.3), RHEL 5 (getopt 1.1.4) and RHEL 6.4 (getopt 1.1.4).

Comment: Very curious.  I have no explanation for what you're seeing.  You haven't gone tinkering with `$IFS`, have you?

Comment: No, Jonathan, I haven't.

Comment: Suggestion: get the source for [`getopt 1.1.5`](http://software.frodo.looijaard.name/getopt/download.php) and compile that, and see whether you get different results using that.  It's supposed to be a 'build fix' release rather than a 'bug fix' release, so in theory it shouldn't make any difference.  Or get the 1.1.4 version from the same URL.  You may need to use `./getopt` in the build directory to invoke it.

Comment: Hey Jonathan. The same behaviour found in a "2.6.28-19-server #66-Ubuntu SMP" machine -- the first test and the last one report 0 (not ambiguous), the other ones report 1 (ambiguous).

Comment: OK; I can reproduce that on Ubuntu 14.04, but the version there is `getopt from util-linux 2.20.1`.  Very curious.  It looks like a bug to me.  Maybe it should be reported to maintainers?  And then the question is 'which maintainers?'  (I note that the current version of [util-linux](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/util-linux/) is 2.24, though that's been out but a few weeks (2014-04-24) so it is not surprising that is not in the distributions yet. Version 2.23 was released 2013-07-31, so it has had more time to be picked up.

Comment: I downloaded util-linux 2.13 and compiled getopt (1.1.4). The same behaviour is found. I guess the getopt_long(3) function is buggy because it returns a LONG_OPT code (meaning "I've found a long option") when an ambiguous option is provided -- it should return a '?'

Comment: I downloaded util-linux 2.13 and compiled getopt. The same behaviour is found.

Comment: When the getopt option "-a" is used (forcing to use the getopt_long_only(3) call), getopt reports correctly that "the option is ambiguous"